# How to get data from local Web API (ASP.NET Core) in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my code when I generate the data to create the Treeview:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export class Product {
     id: string;
     text: string;
     expanded?: boolean;
     items?: Product[];
     price?: number;
     image?: string;
}
```

I created data in Angular like this:

```
var products: Product[] = [{
id: "1",
text: "Stores",
expanded: true,
items: [{
    id: "1_1",
    text: "Super Mart of the West",
    expanded: true,
    items: [{
        id: "1_1_1",
        text: "Video Players",
        items: [{
            id: "1_1_1_1",
            text: "HD Video Player",
            price: 220,
            image: "images/products/1.png"
        }, {
            id: "1_1_1_2",
            text: "SuperHD Video Player",
            image: "images/products/2.png",
            price: 270
        }]
    }, {
        id: "1_1_2",
        text: "Televisions",
        expanded: true,
        items: [{
            id: "1_1_2_1",
            text: "SuperLCD 42",
            image: "images/products/7.png",
            price: 1200
        }, {
            id: "1_1_2_2",
            text: "SuperLED 42",
            image: "images/products/5.png",
            price: 1450              
        }
            ...
        }]
    }
```

This is my output run in Angular:

[image: Output in Angular]

And I don't want to use this way to set data. Can I get data by getting it from the localhost web API (created from ASP.NET Core)?

[image: Local WEB API (Swagger UI - ASP.NET Core)]

Thanks for all your help. I'm just a novice working with Angular (forgive me if my question is silly)!!

Comment: The Angular documentation has a section on using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) to consume a backend service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use this way to set data. Can I get data by getting it from the localhost web API (created from ASP.NET Core)?

If you'd like to make http request(s) from your Angular frontend to your APIs backend to get data, as @DM mentioned in comment, you can try to use HttpClient.

*inject the HttpClient service*

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

*make http request(s)*

```
products: Product[];

GetProducts() {
    this.http.get<Product[]>('https://localhost:44386/api/nodeitems')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
    });
}
```

Besides, you may need to enable CORS on APIs backend app to set the allowed origins.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0